# Could not get access "string" and drawable folder of Rescuers in Composes android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

here is my code, unable to get access string and drawable folder in composes, where i have mistake help appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check if you are importing a different `R` class

Comment: import yourpackgename.R is required for the same.

Comment: please, add your code with correct package name, and also screenshot with package name

Comment: i have put it with package name .R but still not working where i have mistake

Comment: Try out by clean and rebuilding project. Or restart Android Studio. It may be of some AGP build problem.

Comment: not working .....